# How to get the column and row number of a linked cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell in sheet 1 that has a link to a cell in sheet 2.

In sheet 1, cell A1 contains a link as ='sheet2'!A1 which display a value 100 from sheet2 A1

I need to extract column and row number of the linked cell(='sheet2'!A1) and display on sheet1 B1.

Comment: Extracting two values (column and row) into a single cell? Can you display how you see this happen? Please include the wanted result and your own attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below formula to get row and column of linked cell.

```
=ROW(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"=",""))) & "," & COLUMN(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"=","")))
```

[image]

Comment: Worked Perfectly ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following formula only works because you are using a direct cell reference.  ie there is no formula in the cell surrounding the cell address.

```
=RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(A1),LEN(FORMULATEXT(A1))-FIND("!",FORMULATEXT(A1)))
```

[image: POC]

This method will preserve the $ notation if the reference address is fixed.  If you need actual column number instead of its letter, take a look a Huran24HR's answer.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back. Huran24HR answer was right.